# Button from customised ListView does not respond

Tags: android, listview, listitem

When I click the button no message appears, but if I click on the listview item and then click the button then it shows the message.

what is want is to update my database by clicking on each listview items's button. I have used `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in `list_items.xml` button.

```
productListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            Button saleBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sale_btn);
            if (saleBtn != null) {
                saleBtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } 
        }

    });
```

The items layout for `list_items.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sale_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Sale"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#2B3D4D"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Product" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#2B3D4D"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Quantity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#2B3D4D"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Price" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide your items layout.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i1emQfn8 this is the link for the list_item.xml

Comment: Looks Okay, did you try to single step debug that code?

Comment: No. i didn't try that.

Comment: yes. That is the way i found online https://coderanch.com/t/442573/View-customised-ListView . But it works after i clicked on the list item.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
View button = productListView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.sale_btn);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

instead of finding the button using the view and the id which will only prompt toast when you press the first button in the list you have created instead of the individual button in the list using `getChildAt()` you can get the individual button in the list

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes i tried that too. same output.

Comment: @osh huh that is strange you're using list view right??

Comment: @osh try restarting your android studio cause i am not sure what is causing the hiccup

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll restart and let know.

Comment: No luck it's still the same :(

Comment: @osh sorry dude i have no clue what is going on then